# Displaying Math with MathJax

Tags: html, mathjax

I am trying to learn how to display math equations with MathJax. I tweaked this code from codepen and this works fine:

```
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
<style>
p {
    font-size: 22px;
}
</style>

</head><body>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$', '$']] },
    elements: ['math']
  });
</script>

<p id="math">
Find the value of: 
$\Huge{\frac {3.41 \times 10^3}{1.80 \times 10^2}}$
and enter the answer within the box.
</p>
```

`

However, when I add one more paragraph and enter math in there, it does not display as math. It just displays like text. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you including your new paragraph element in the elements array within the mathjax config?  If you look at the elements array in your example your including the element with id="math" which is your existing paragraph

Comment: Ok, that did it. When I added the id of the other <p>, it displays fine. Thank you!

Comment: You should choose my answer so others with the same question will be able to find the solution easily ;)

Comment: I am trying to choose your answer, but I cannot. How can I do it? I am new to Stackoverflow. Sorry.

Comment: Since your answer registered as a comment to my post, I think it does not allow me to choose your answer. I cannot up vote my own post, it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your next paragraph id in the `elements: ['math']` array in your MathJax config.

Comment: Ok, there I did it! However, since I am a newbie to Stack overflow, it may not show my up votes.